# Mimick Sheetrock “texture”

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

OK so I have a regular drywall house… What I’ve noticed is that when you use joint compound to fix hole etc. the joint compound is incredibly smooth yet the drywall surrounding the patch has a little bit of texture to it…

How does one replicate that standard drywall texture  not orange peel or anything popcorn like, just standard drywall with paint.

[image: heres a very badly sanded, and painted patch that was like this when I moved in, reguardless that the edges look horrible you can still tell the smoothness of the patch vs the slight texture to the drywall]

Here’s a more recent example that I just finished mudding and sanding ... if I simply just prime and paint it’s going to be noticeable!

Any recommendations??

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not the paper, it's the rolled paint.   The orange peel texture comes from the paint roller.  To match that, you will need to put a couple coats on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't painted over your patch:
The 1st thing I would do is take a damp sponge, and feather the edges of your patches. For this, damp doesn't mean dripping wet and not nearly dry, but somewhere in between. To feather the edge, start about an inch inside the patch from the edges, and with almost no pressure, swipe from inside the patch to outside several times until you can't see the hard edge anymore.

If you have painted over the patch:
Be sure to use a putty knife that's at least a few inches wide and is very flexible. Take your putty knife and load it so you have mud that goes from one edge to about 1/2" toward the center for a total of about 1/2" long. Apply your blade to the wall so it's just about flat against the wall with heavy emphasis on the outer edge. The will flex the blade and cause a feathering type action and make the outer edge nearly indistinguishable from the existing wall to your patch. If needed, apply a very dry, damp sponge with light touch to complete the feathering.

Texture/Painting:
As far as texture goes, it looks to be a heavy roller stipple, the texture a roller leaves behind on a smooth wall. I would guess it was made with a roller with 3/8" nap, but it might be 1/2" too; it's hard to tell with the pictures. Be sure to let the mud fully dry before painting for either option above. Do not drown your roller in paint or it will be too thick and hard to feather the paint. Start in the middle of the patch and roll in straight lines from the middle until you can hardly tell the wall has new paint. This will help preventing the new paint from looking like an obvious touch up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To get a specific type of texture is one of the toughest jobs.

first you need to hide any marks sometimes This requires fading a patch in over a foot or more. You have a small orifice small pull wet spatter on my gun.

Probably did not help at all. Mud guns have different sizes of orifices this kinda denotes the max size of the detail.
then there is pull back how much mud can enter the area and get picked up by the air stream how heavy or thick it is.

so you have a small orifice with not much pull back or not much mud can flow last it has no shape so it was shot wet this takes time and even then I mis give a trial shot and adjust when I get it close enough I work from the bare center putting dow a slightly heavy coat moving our further away and quick to fade the new and old together.

There are cans of texture if an orange peal and a small job I won’t get my gun dirty I will buy a can but if a heavy spatter or large area its cans don’t do well there, I have only used the cans a few times and don’t remember much variety, to get a good match you need a mud gun and some practice, mud is cheap, I bought an all plastic gun a long time ago it was fairly cheap under 75? But 1 time not cleaning or using hot mud the cheap and even a 300$ gun can be ruined.

Some may try to use a sponge that won’t look right with your existing texture and sometimes if you can’t match that wall just shoot the entire wall with a heavy orange peal.

matching texture is a art I am no artist but after a while you figure out the basics of your gun then it is not as hard. Small , small, wet mud should get you there.

Comment: OP said "I have a regular drywall house" the texture is from the paper in the drywall.

Comment: @joe Drywall paper is smooth,  texture on drywall is added and comes from a texture sprayer or a heavy nap or stipple roller.

Comment: @Alaska Man OP said "How does one replicate that standard drywall texture not orange peel or anything popcorn like, just standard drywall with paint." There is a difference between the texture of drywall and joint compound.

Comment: @joe Alaska man is correct drywall is just paper. It is extremely rare not to have some texture unless a wall for a projection TV.  I put what the photos look like to me and AM said he thought it was different like heavy nap or roller, yes you could get close but there would be lines with a roller in my opinion but we can’t see much so both methods could be used to match that patched area something will look better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for truly seamless drywall that is not textured, you need to do the opposite. apply a thin skim coat of compound over the entire surface A.K.A. level five drywall finish.

(The first picture looks like it could have been sanded down better). Try to spread the mud over a larger area and feather the edges.

Comment: Sigh lol what am I going to do the whole wall? Where’s that end! I do one wall I gotta do the other all because of a small silly patch job. I can’t believe they don’t make something to mimic the Sheetrock paper face!

Comment: @Tony Regular drywall installations have this irregularity at every seam. Google California patch (a method of using drywall to make a patch). Use paper instead of fiberglass tape to minimize thickness.